# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:No qualifying bean of type[com.library.service.BookService]found for dependency:expected at least 1 bean

Tags: spring

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.library.service.BookService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2522)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2511)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

****My Library-servlet.xml****

```
<!-- Use @Component annotations for bean definitions -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.library" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- View resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- TX -->

<bean id="global-tm" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="global-em" />
</bean>

<!-- Entity Manager -->
<bean id="global-em"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:packagesToScan="com.library.entity" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.hibernate.dialectClass}" />
</bean>

<!-- Transaction -->

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="global-tm" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

My web.xml

```
<!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for 
    handling all application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Library</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/Library-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Library</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:jpaContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
```

My controller

```
@Autowired
BookService bookService;

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(BookController.class);

@RequestMapping(value = "/bookEntry")
public String bookEntry(Model model) {
    LOG.info("Displaying book entry form");
    BookCommandForm bookCommandForm = new BookCommandForm();
    model.addAttribute(bookCommandForm);
    String view = "BookEntry";
    return view;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/bookSaved")
public String saveBook(Model model,
        @ModelAttribute("bookCommandForm") BookCommandForm bookCommandForm) {
    LOG.info("New book Registration begins.");
    BookDTO bookDTO = new BookDTO();
    bookDTO.setBookName(bookCommandForm.getBookName());
    bookDTO.setBookAuthor(bookCommandForm.getBookAuthor());
    bookDTO.setBookEdition(bookCommandForm.getBoookEdition());
    bookService.saveBook(bookDTO);
    LOG.info("New book registered successfully.");
    String view = "BookSaved";
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Make sure `BookService.java` is annotated with `@Service`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had missed the @Service for BookService.java.